# call method that rounds java

Tags: java, methods, casting, formatting

OK so I can't understand why it says the method isn't being used locally.... The private String formatNumber() method is saying this.

Basically what I need to do is have a method that returns the circumference
- another method that rounds numbers to 2 decimal places and returns a string
- and another method that returns the formatted version of circumference...

It's not hard to see what I'm trying to do, but it gives me the above stated error and I can't figure it out.

```
//figures out circumference
public  double getCircumference(){

    circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

    return circumference;


}
    //takes string and turns back into a double
public double getFormattedCircumference(){

    double x = Double.parseDouble(format);
    return x;


}
//this method is giving the error of not being used locally...
    //method takes double and turns to string so that it can be formatted and it
      has to be a string
private String formatNumber(double x){

    x = circumference;
    NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    number.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    String format = number.format(x);
    return format;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've declared the private method but you've not used it in your current code anywhere and so the compiler is warning you of this (check your program to see if you're calling this method anywhere).

Incidentally, what you're seeing is a *warning* not an *error*. Your code should still compile, and the program will still run (if there are no errors present).

---

**Edit 1**
You've a serious problem with the method, and maybe more than one, in that it takes in a double parameter and then promptly discards it. Why? If you want to format the number that is passed in as a parameter, then you don't want to discard that parameter. Also, do you want to make this method  `public` so that it can be called by objects outside of this class? Also, will the method have state or will it be stateless? Will it use the fields of the class, or will it only format the number passed into it. If the latter, than it should be a `static` method.

Comment: ah ok. So i'll have to set it up so that the getFormattedCircumference calls that private method? Right? then I can actually display the correct number in the main class.

Comment: Sorry about that should have said constructor...  It will only format the number passed into it and it will be used to format area and circumference.

Answer (score 0):

I got it all figured out. I was making it harder than it actually was.

```
//figures out circumference
public  double getCircumference(){

circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

return circumference;


}

public String getFormattedCircumference(){

return formatNumber(getCircumference());

}


//formats to two decimal places.
private String formatNumber(double x){

NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
number.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String format = number.format(x);
return format;
}
```